# How to manipulate JSON elements

Tags: javascript, json

Can somebody please tell me how to manipulate JSON in JavaScript. I have ajax parsed JSON response like this

```
var json = [
{"year": "2015","product": "Matcha Latte","value": 43.3},
{"year": "2016","product": "Matcha Latte","value": 85.8}, 
{"year": "2015","product": "Milk Tea","value": 83.1},
{"year": "2016","product": "Milk Tea","value": 73.4},
{"year": "2015","product": "Cheese Cocoa","value": 86.4},
{"year": "2016","product": "Cheese Cocoa","value": 65.2},
{"year": "2015","product": "Walnut Brownie","value": 72.4},
{"year": "2016","product": "Walnut Brownie","value": 53.9}]
```

And I would like to have this in order to send the JSON to a chart

```
json_to_chart = 
[{product: 'Matcha Latte', '2015': 43.3, '2016': 85.8},
{product: 'Milk Tea', '2015': 83.1, '2016': 73.4},
{product: 'Cheese Cocoa', '2015': 86.4, '2016': 65.2},
{product: 'Walnut Brownie', '2015': 72.4, '2016': 53.9}]
```

I think I need to group first by product. I used lodash.js

```
var json_grouped = _(json).groupBy('product').value();
```

then I need to create a new JSON object and feed it product and dynamic new key "year" with value "value"!?

Can somebody tell me how to do it?

Comment: First thing here, let's clear up some terminology. 'JSON' is just a data transfer and storage format. You receive data from your ajax as JSON, just like you said, but once it's serialized/ deciphered, it's now just a generic, plain, Javascript object (Or Array, in this specific case). JSON doesn't have anything to do with the data manipulation you're wanting to achieve.

Comment: Based on your function example, are you using Underscore.js?

Comment: Edited: I used lodash library

Comment: `var json = [{"year": "2015","product": "Milk Tea","value": 83.1},{"year": "2016","product": "Milk Tea","value": 73.4}];
var op = [];
function findIfExists(key){
     return op.findIndex(function(element){
      return  element.product == key;});
}
for(let i=0;i< json.length;i++){
    if( findIfExists(json[i].product) == -1){
       var obj = {}; obj.product = json[i].product;
       obj[json[i].year] = json[i].value;
       op.push(obj);
    }else{
       var index = findIfExists(json[i].product);
       op[index][json[i].year] = json[i].value;
    }
 }
 console.log(op);`

Comment: Thanks @Ishank exactly the result I needed

Comment: that's for my own record! Also, this is O(n^2) as of now if we use an object to track the presence of an object in `op` then this will be O(n) :)

Comment: @JecaTechy the `findIndex ` is not supported in IE so if you are going to use it in client-side make sure to include the polyfill